# Using Variable to DataTables Server-Side Column value Formatter

Tags: php, datatables, server-side

I want to pass PHP function on each cell of DataTables via Server-side Formatter, but PHP Function is dynamic. Here is example code:

```
$func_apply = $_GET['function_name']; // trim | strip_tags | md5 | ucwords

$columns[] = array(
'db'        => $field,
'dt'        => '3',
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
                return $func_apply($d);
            }
);
```

But this way I am getting PHP error Undefined variable: $func_apply
And if I put global $func_apply; within anonymous function then it gives Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue by using the PHP Closures:

```
$func_apply = $_GET['function_name']; // trim | strip_tags | md5 | ucwords

$columns[] = array(
'db'        => $field,
'dt'        => '3',
'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) use ($func_apply) {
            return $func_apply($d);
        }
);
```